# Image bug in overleaf

Tags: debugging

I was programing in overleaf, and after i added a new image and recompilate, all my other images just bugged. How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: you mean your images got the grey stripes? That's odd but looks more like a problem in the viewer. Are they still there if you stop and re-start the web browser?

Comment: Yes, is the striped. Aparently is just with the viewer, after i generated the pdf it's gone

Comment: there is not much we can say here with no way to reproduce. If it occurs again you should contact support at overleaf, they can see into your project and see if there is anything crashing the built on viewer.

Comment: That's probably your browser's PDF viewer messing with the image.